# How I can group timestamp column to hourly and aggregate the rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with data for each minutes, it also contains a `date` column which is used to keep track of the date in timestamp format.

Here I'm trying to aggregate the data by hours instead of minute.

I tried the following code which is working but it needs to index based on `date` column which I don't want because then I cannot loop through the dataframe using `df.loc` function.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np

date_rng = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', end='1/08/2018', freq='T')
df = pd.DataFrame(date_rng, columns=['date'])
df['data'] = np.random.randint(0,100,size=(len(date_rng)))

df.set_index('date')
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, unit='s')
df = df.resample('H').sum()
df.head(15)
```

I also tried groupby but it's not working, following is the code.

```
df.groupby([df.date.dt.hour]).data.sum()
print(df.head(15))
```

How I can groupby `date` without indexing it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`pd.Grouper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) and specify the `freq` parameter:

```
df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='1H')]).sum()
```

Full code:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np

date_rng = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', end='1/08/2018', freq='T')
df = pd.DataFrame(date_rng, columns=['date'])
df['data'] = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(len(date_rng)))

print(df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='1H')]).sum())
#                      data
# date
# 2018-01-01 00:00:00  2958
# 2018-01-01 01:00:00  3084
# 2018-01-01 02:00:00  2991
# 2018-01-01 03:00:00  3021
# 2018-01-01 04:00:00  2894
# ...                   ...
# 2018-01-07 20:00:00  2863
# 2018-01-07 21:00:00  2850
# 2018-01-07 22:00:00  2823
# 2018-01-07 23:00:00  2805
# 2018-01-08 00:00:00    25

# [169 rows x 1 columns]
```

Hope that helps !

Comment: Thanks for the help! but it again adding `date` as an index, can we avoid that? I did a `df.reset_index()` that's working but not sure whether that's the right way of doing this.

Comment: Yes you're right ! The `groupby` function set the columns used as index. Using `reset_index()` a good way to go !